# Getting Error when initilializing jquery ui dialog, how to proceed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, error-handling

I've used `jQueryUI` successfully with other websites, but for a particular one I'm working on right now, whenever I try to initialize `$("#dialog").dialog()`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$( "#dialog" ).dialog()')
```

I'm not sure how to proceed, I already changed sources on all three source files to see if that fixed it, but no luck (`jQuery`, `jQueryUI.js` and `jQueryUI.css`).

How can I figure out what the error is?

Comment: Looks like jquery-ui isn't loaded, use the dev tools net panel to view the scripts that are downloaded and ensure they are downloading successfully. If they are, my only other guess is wrap your dialog code in a `$(document).ready()`

Comment: The code you show is correct, and you state that you have included the libraries. Next step is to show us more of your code and let us play a game of `spot the error`.

Comment: Provide more html code

Answer (score 0):

I found that I accidentally had links to two different jQuery libraries:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is what was causing the issue.

Thanks to those who chimed in.